# Ошибка "Невозможно получить свойство lookup класса worksheetfunction" при попытке протестировать вывод функции

Tags: vba

Написал буквально 3 строчки кода, чтобы протестировать вывод функции Lookup.
При выполнении появилась ошибка "Невозможно получить свойство lookup класса worksheetfunction".

```
Sub TestLookUp()

Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Lookup(Sheets("Результат").Cells(2, 1).Value, Sheets("Список А").Range("A2:B4200"), Sheets("Список А").Range("B2:B4200"))

End Sub
```

Файл доступен по [ссылке](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cyCCc7HPI6Z2dZApWk60YkWTUqJJ3Vx7/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Вы используете array form функции Lookup (второй параметр не является вектором). В такой форме функция не имеет третьего параметра.

Comment: Application.WorksheetFunction...

Comment: `Sub TestLookUp()

Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.Lookup(Sheets("Ðåçóëüòàò").Cells(2, 1).Value, Sheets("Ñïèñîê À").Range("A2:B4200"))

End Sub` 

Исправил код, но не помогло. Ошибка та же самая

Answer (score 0):

Как раз тот вариант, когда ознакомление с данными помогает понять проблему.

Для работы функции `LOOKUP (ПРОСМОТР)` требуется, чтобы диапазон поиска был отсортирован по убыванию.

Если сортировка столбца *А* на листе *Список А* невозможа, применяйте другие функции с поиском точного совпадения (`ВПР`, `ИНДЕКС/ПОИСКПОЗ`)

```
Debug.Print Application.VLookup(Sheets("Результат").Cells(2, 1).Value, Sheets("Список А").Range("A2:B4200"), 2, 0)

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        Debug.Print .Index(Sheets("Список А").Range("B2:B4200"), .Match(Sheets("Результат").Cells(2, 1).Value, Sheets("Список А").Range("A2:A4200"), 0))
    End With
```

Функции листа работают быстрее кода `VBA`, но если применяются непосредственно в `Excel`. Вызов же функций листа из `VBA` - процесс сравнительно медленный, поэтому результат правильнее получать собственными средствами языка

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогло